# ios - How to load javascript into a UIWebview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to load javascript into a UIWebview,here is the javascript code

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
window.external =
{
    'Notify': function(s) { document.location = 'acs://settoken?token=' + s; },
    'notify': function(s) { document.location = 'acs://settoken?token=' + s; }
};
</script>

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   //Here how to call the above javascript
  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"";
}
```

Comment: refer this[http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview)

Comment: You already know what method to use. What problem(s) are you having with it?

Comment: I know that method,but when i'm trying to implement that javascript code i'm getting an error like Expecting '[' token and characters are too constant,so can you please show me how to call?I'm just the beginner

Comment: @userXXX Instead of messing with JavaScript-injection into web views, you'd better **at least learn the syntax of the language.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close webview statement.
Your code should be like this:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.external =\
{\
'Notify': function(s) { document.location = 'acs://settoken?token=' + s; },\
'notify': function(s) { document.location = 'acs://settoken?token=' + s; }\
}"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method to call the `javascript` from `html` to `iOS` `webview`

```
  [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"my_html_function();"];
```

this may help you.